# Undefined reference to function (linker error)

Tags: c++, linker

Hi i read the other questions and answers about undefined reference.But still i'm not able to find out what are the problems with my code. I have a simple linked list code wherein i add the integers to the tail and after that i display them. Here is my code 
"head.h"

```
#ifndef __HEAD_H_INCLUDE
#define __HEAD_H_INCLUDE

class Node {
int info;
Node *next;
};

class imple {
public:
    imple();
    void addToTail(int );
    void display(void);
private:
    Node *head,*tail;
};

#endif
```

"implementaion.cpp"

```
#include<iostream>
#include "head.h"

imple::imple(){
head=tail=0;
}

void imple::addToTail(int key){
if(tail==0)
    {tail=head=new Node();
    info=key;next=0;}
else
{
    tail->next=new Node();
    info=key;next=0;
    tail=tail->next;
}
}

void imple::display(){
Node *temp;
for(temp=head;temp->next !=0;temp=temp->next)
{
    std::cout<<temp->info << "   ";
}
}
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include<iostream>
#include "head.h"

int main(){
Node node;
imple ab;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
ab.addToTail(i);
ab.display();
}
```

Everytime i compile i get this error

"/tmp/cc20Z1ZH.o: In function `main':
lmain.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to`imple::imple()'
lmain.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `imple::addToTail(int)'
lmain.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to`imple::display()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Your answers and suggestions will be helpful

Comment: How do you compile? What is the compilation command line?

Comment: What does your command line look like ? Are you actually compiling `implementaion.cpp` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you may use

```
g++ main.cpp implementation.cpp -o out
```

---

You need to include `implementation.cpp`in your building process and make the function definitions accessible to the linker. That is, compile it with

```
g++ -c implementation.cpp -o implementation.o
```

and

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

and link them together with

```
g++ main.o implementation.o -o out
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
g++ main.cpp implementaion.cpp
```

Probably this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a run file with:

```
g++ -o main implementation.cpp main.cpp
```

and run it with :

```
./main
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to finish your thought here? I'm confused by this answer.